# We have multiple environments and right now one of the environment has to return response header in upper case and other in lower case

Tags: karate

I want response header case is ignored how to achieve this?

- def header = karate.get("responseHeaders['Content-Type'][0]")
- print 'header---------', header

If content-type is lower case it prints the value as null while it is present but in upper case how to get response header so it is not case sensitive.

Output:

```
header--------- null
```

I tried this too but it always only read first condition

```
* def header = karate.get("responseHeaders['Content-Type'][0]" || "responseHeaders['content-type'][0]")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reading the docs, search for `lowerCaseResponseHeaders`:

[image]

You can find an example of use [here](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/v1.1.0/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/headers/content-type.feature)

```
* configure lowerCaseResponseHeaders = true
```